# Nginx refuses to read new directory in /home

Tags: nginx, permissions, centos6, php-fpm

I'm on CentOS6.6, installed "Akeneo" and all went well.

Installed into `/home/pim` so the actual location for nginx to use is the `web` directory where `app.php` is located.

Doing a `namei` on `/home/pim/web/app.php` shows:

```
f: /home/pim/web/app.php
dr-xr-xr-x root  root  /
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx home
drwxrwxrwx nginx nginx pim
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx web
-rwxrwxr-x nginx nginx app.php
```

Nginx is using:

```
user nginx nginx;
worker_processes  4;
```

And PHP-FPM is using:

```
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0660

; Unix user/group of processes
user = nginx
group = nginx
```

Anyonan idea on why this isn't working? I've been playing for hours with the permissions now. Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: If SELinux is in Enforcing mode, it won't let you do that... Try changing this boolean to true: `setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs on`

Comment: Ahh you're a hero, it indeed was in enforcing mode. Thanks!

Comment: Sweet, I have expanded my comment into an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If SELinux is in Enforcing mode, it won't let you do that... Try changing this boolean to true:

```
setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs on
```

Please note, I don't recommend disabling SELinux!
There are many tools out there which can help you use SELinux to secure your system.

- Please see the CentOS documentation here: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux
- Also, check out my favorite video on the topic: [SELinux For Mere Mortals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bQqX3RWn0Yw)

Comment: You rock! I literally looked for this solution for hours before realizing the problem was SELinux not being able to access the home directories. Thanks!

Comment: Note that I needed to set `httpd_read_user_content` to `on` as well to get it working.